# Get RGBA values from decoded PNG image

Tags: image, dart

The task at hand is to read a PNG image as bytes, get the RGBA values of each pixel, apply modifications and set new pixels in the image. So far this is the code I have:

```
import 'package:image/image.dart' as img;

final byteData = await rootBundle.load('assets/images/image.png');
img.Image image = img.Image.fromBytes(1536, 2048, byteData.buffer.asInt8List(), format: img.Format.rgba);
print(image.getPixelSafe(0, 0));
```

Applying it to [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0bVd.png), I get the integer value 1196314761. How do I convert this integer into RGBA or hex format?

If this is the wrong way to get a specific pixel, how can I do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you'll need to properly decode the image, which you are not currently doing. Use the `Decoder` class instead of trying to directly pass your encoded data to the `Image` constructor.

```dart
img.Image image = PngDecoder().decodeImage(byteData.buffer.asInt8List());
```

---

The package you're using returns the color as

> a Uint32 as #AABBGGRR

To get the colors you want individually, just extract each of those bytes from the Uint32. The following code does a bitwise `&` to obtain only the least significant byte. Bit shifts are done to get higher bytes.

```dart
int input = image.getPixelSafe(0, 0);

int red = input & 0xff;
int green = input >> 8 & 0xff;
int blue = input >> 8 * 2 & 0xff;
int alpha = input >> 8 * 3 & 0xff;
```

---

To get this as a hex string you can do `red.toRadixString(16)`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Applying this code doesn't give the exact colours at the position. Also, I just noticed that the int values from (0, 0) to (20, 0) for two different PNG images are the same. How can I get the colour values from the image?

Comment: @vaishnav I noticed you're not decoding the image file. The data passed to the image class is PNG encoded data, not RGBA data. I'll make an edit showing how to do that.

Comment: Ah yes, thanks for that. Not sure why, but decoding the image returns null. Have you faced this before?

Comment: @vaishnav See my latest edit. Use the `PngDecoder` class, not the general `Decoder` class.

Comment: Thanks. My mistake was that I tried decoding the byte data as an `Int8List` instead of a `Uint8List'. Works perfectly now.